# zsh completion: complete files in given directory

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

My script takes optional parameters (-i, -w) and a filename in a given directory. How can I tell zsh to complete only regular files (not directories or symlinks) in `$HOME/data`

This is what I have in my `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_my-script`.

```
#compdef my-script

_my-script() {
    integer ret=1
    local -a args
    args+=(
    '-i[case insensitive]'
    '-w[match whole words]'
    )

    _arguments $args[@] && ret=0
    return ret
}

_my-script
```

where do I add the `_files` and how do I tell `zsh` to only complete regular files in `$HOME/data` ?

Also, I assume the firs line `#compdef my-script` is not a comment. How can I add comment to my completion file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file name is argument 1, so pass `1` to [`_arguments`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005farguments). Position 1 takes (is) an argument, so the argument to `_arguments` looks like `1:description:code to do the completion`. To specify which files to complete, pass options to [`_files`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005ffiles), some of which are inherited from [`_path_files`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fpath_005ffiles): `-W` to complete inside a given directory, `-g` to match a specific pattern which can include [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to restrict file types. Use `_path_files` instead of `_files` because `_files` always offers directories, whereas with `_path_files` directories are not offered if `-g` doesn't let them through.

```
args=( …
  '1:thing:_path_files -W ~/data -g "*(.)"'
)
```

If you want to write a comment, just write a comment the normal way. [`#compdef …`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Autoloaded-files) on the first line is a magic comment that tells zsh that this file contains a completion function for `my-script`. It's equivalent to having `compdef _my-script my-script` in your init file. It needs to be on the first line.

Comment: thank you. but it still shows directories in the completions. Can I ignore directories entirely? I am only interested in first level files.

Comment: @400theCat Ah yes, forgot about that. Use `_path_files` instead of `_files`.